# How to assemble pdf from HTTP stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, pdf-generation

I'm using a 3rd party html to pdf conversion (DocRaptor).  You POST your HTML to their site and they respond with the PDF.  The starter code they give you works fine, but it puts the file to your harddrive.  I modified their code to get it to come through the browser and as a file download.  So I'm 100% confident the data I'm getting from the HTTP response is good data.  I can't seem to assemble it back to a useable file.

I'm reasonably confident the issue is how I'm handing the responseStream data.  It all seems to go wrong once I enter the Try/Catch.  I'm very new to c# and web programming, so I would very much appreciate some guidance from the SO users here.  Thanks.  Here is my code.

```
            string postData = String.Format(PostFormat,
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentContent) ? "document_url" : "document_content"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentContent) ? DocumentURL : DocumentContent),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Name),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(type),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Test.ToString().ToLower()),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Strict),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PrinceOptions));

        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(DocRaptorUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()) { dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); }

        System.IO.Stream stream = null;

        try 
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    var filepath = @"C:\Users\David\Downloads\UberwriterUSRReport.pdf";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                    // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=UberwriterUSRReport.pdf"));

                    stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

                    CopyStream(responseStream, stream);

                    long bytestToRead = stream.Length;

                    while (bytestToRead > 0)
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];  
                            int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                            bytestToRead = bytestToRead - length;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bytestToRead = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it your intention to save the file to the hardrive before sending it to the browser? Cause that is what you're (incorrectly) doing now.

Best is to enclose the write action in a using statement, cause I don't see you close the stream anywhere:

```
stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

Here you're saving to the file:

```
CopyStream(responseStream, stream);
```

Next, you're trying to read your outputstream (with which you just saved the file), to write that to your Response.Outputstream. And you have allready a copystream implementation, so why do it manually here? :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
```

So, I would say it should be something like:

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var filepath = @"C:\Users\David\Downloads\UberwriterUSRReport.pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=UberwriterUSRReport.pdf"));

        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Create)) {
          CopyStream(responseStream, stream);
        }

        using (var readstream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Read)) {
            CopyStream(readstream, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to save the file on the server at all:

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // let the browser know how to open the PDF document, attachment or inline, and the file name
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=UberwriterUSRReport.pdf"));

      CopyStream(responseStream, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, it worked.  I'll admit I don't know why exactly.  I had to edit one thing in your suggestion to get it to work.  Instead of FileMode.Read, I used FileMode.Open.  "Read" was not an option offered to me when I coded your solution up.

Comment: Nice to see it worked. I have to admit I did it by heart, so I'm not surprised there was an error :)

Comment: It worked locally for me, but I just published it to Azure and a choked.  I'm thinking the filepath is the issue.  Can I take the responseStream and have it go right to the browswer as if it were a file that was downloaded?  That is what I really want anyway.  I just want the user to click the button, a PDF gets generated, and it shows up as a download on the client side.

Comment: Yes, the second snippet should do just that

Answer (score 1):

MUCHO thanks much to Stephen for putting me on the right path.  I further refined the implementation.  I had more code that what was required.  All I want is the user to hit a button, post the HTML to the DocRaptor.com site, have them respond with the generated PDF, and that file to appear as a download in the browser.  Here is the final implemented code as tested on Azure.

```
            try 
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    //var filepath = @"C:\Users\David\Downloads\UberwriterUSRReport.pdf";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("atachment; filename=UberwriterUSRReport.pdf"));
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

                    CopyStream(responseStream, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

                }
            }
        }
```